# Saving / Editing Variables in a 'Plist' File?

Tags: iphone, string, variables, plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Dev - Edit objects in Array from Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476968/iphone-dev-edit-objects-in-array-from-plist)

I have a number of different variables like strings and integers that I want to save into a 'Plist' that I already have set up. I'm already reading the 'Plist' however I'm unsure of how to alter and save variables back into the 'Plist' afterwards.

*UPDATE*

I'm already using the following code to load up the plist file and read the keys in the 'viewDidLoad' method.

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"questions" ofType:@"plist"];
categories = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Within my 'Plist' I have an array for each item, which I then read.

```
pair = [categories objectAtIndex:questionCounter]; 

plistQuestion = [pair objectAtIndex:0];
plistAnswer = [pair objectAtIndex:1];
plistAnswer2 = [pair objectAtIndex:2];
completed = [pair objectAtIndex:3];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *foo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"file.plist"];
[foo setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"baz"];
[foo writeToFile:@"file.plist" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you plist is array based not dictionary based (which was not known at the time this was answered). It's the same principle - load the plist into an NSMutableArray instead of an NSArray, replace, add or remove objects from it, and write back to the file.