# iPhone Dev - Edit objects in Array from Plist

Tags: iphone, arrays, object, plist, save

I have a Plist in which I have a number of Array's. Within these arrays are different objects that I'm reading, I've become stuck however on editing these objects in the array and then saving the array back to the Plist file again.

I'm already reading the file like so...

```
Array = [myArrays objectAtIndex:arrayCounter]; //This tells it which Array to load.

myObject = [Array objectAtIndex:0]; //This reads that object in the array. (This is what I want to edit.)
```

I was wondering how I would go about editing that object (it's a string) and then saving it back into the array and then saving that array back into the Plist file where it is stored.

Thanks in advance!

P.S - I'm willing to post more code or information if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save data in application's main bundle instead you have to do in document directory like this:

```
 NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPAth:plistFilePath]) 
{//plist already exits in doc dir so save content in it

 NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
 NSArray *arrValue = [data objectAtIndex:arrayCounter];

 NSString *strValue = [arrValue objectAtIndex:0];
 strValue = [strValue stringByAppending:@"hello"]; //change your value here

 [[data objectAtIndex:arrayCounter] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:strValue]; //value replaced
 [data writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES];
}
else{ //firstly take content from plist and then write file document directory. it will be executed only once

 NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
 NSArray *arrValue = [data objectAtIndex:arrayCounter];

 NSString *strValue = [arrValue objectAtIndex:0];
 strValue = [strValue stringByAppending:@"hello"]; //change your value here

 [[data objectAtIndex:arrayCounter] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:strValue]; //value replaced
 [data writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: My Plist files are in my supporting files folder, are you saying that I have to save all of these to the document directory in the iPhone?

Comment: yes i will have save in doc dir as u cannot update application bundle file.

Comment: For Plists that I'm not editing is it ok to keep them with the main bundle?

Comment: yes plist is readonly and u cannot update in app bundle but u can keep it if not editing

Comment: I've been looking at the code and I'm confused as to which piece of code is actually saving the plist to the documents directory?

Comment: I understand that part but which bit specifically saves the plist file in the document directory?

Comment: both saves to document directory but false which will be excuted first time in saving to doc dir and next time it will be on true part it has .plist file in doc dir

Comment: So when false it executes the code to save to it in the document directory, which line is it that does this?