# save NSDate value to plist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsdate

I am trying to figure out how to save a NSDate value into my plist file thats in my application.

I am currently doing this but am stuck on the actual part where I have to save it.

```
NSString *datePlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"my-Date" ofType: @"plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: datePlistPath];

        // to be saved to plist
        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

// this is where I start to get abit lost, I want to set the date to the right plist value then commit the changes
        [dict setObject:date forKey:@"my-Date"];
        [dict writeToFile:datePlistPath atomically:YES]; // error happening here.
```

any help would be appreciated

UPDATE: once it hits the last line of code there this is the error that is generated...

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: does the datePlistPath(filePath) exists?

Comment: yep, I know this because I am able to read from it :P I have updated with the error I am getting in my logg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: datePlistPath];
```

it **provide u NSDictionary** not NSMutableDictionary if u use **NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile**

Also u cannot update plist in application bundle instead store in Document Directory.

Refer [dit-objects-in-array-from-plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476968/iphone-dev-edit-objects-in-array-from-plist/12477466#12477466) link

Comment: oh okay.. so thats why its not updating now.. lol blinking heck what a pain in the bum! going to go read up about that now.. thank you very much for your help your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think solution in your case is simple like

Replace

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: datePlistPath];
```

with

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: datePlistPath];
```

Comment: Hrmm.. How can I achieve the desired result of saving my date to the plist then? I have done a bunch of reading.. and I cannot find any solutions..

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: datePlistPath];
```

replace `NSDictionary` with `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: yes, I did exactly what you did at one point which is what caused the other weird error.. and after MSK's solution I clicked as to why this is wrong...  if you look at your code you have **NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary** it should be **NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary** thank you for trying to help however.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a file to

> NSBundle

. Files can be stored only in Documents directory, temp directory and some pre defined locations. you can try the following code. It worked fine for me.

> NSArray *paths =
>   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
>   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
>
> NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
>   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.plist"];
>
> ```
> NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
> NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary new];
> [d setObject:currentDate forKey:@"my-date"];
>
> [d writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to files in your own bundle. You don't say exactly what you are using the date for, but if you just want to persist this one `NSDate` across launches, you probably want to write this date to `NSUserDefaults`.

Docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/

Your code to write it would just look like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date forKey:@"my-Date"];
```

and to read it back you would do

```
NSDate* myDate = (NSDate*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"my-Date"];
// Be prepared for a nil value if this has never been set.
```